# For tensorflow, What's the differences between ResourceApplyAdam and ApplyAdam?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any differences on features or performance between them, or it's just an alias for different version.

Answer (score 1):

return types are different. see reference

```
tensorflow::ops::ResourceApplyAdam
Returns: the created Operation

tensorflow::ops::ApplyAdam
Output: Same as "var".
```

reference
[ResourceApplyAdam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/resource-apply-adam) 
[ApplyAdam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/apply-adam)

Answer (score 1):

Read the Documentation carefully, along with return type, public attributes, public functions are also different
[Resource apply adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/resource-apply-adam)
[Apply Adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/apply-adam)